# JavaScript dynamic Line Charts with many points (~500,000)

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, linechart

I am surveying JavaScript charting solutions for building interactive dashboards. The dashboard is going to have 15 charts, each with 6 lines, and each line has ~5000 points (15 * 6 * 5000 = 450,000). And a new point will be appended (and an old point be removed) to each line about every 3 secs. In addition, I want interactive box zooming and tooltips.

Is this possible without intervalizing(downsampling) the source data? Can anyone recommend JavaScript solutions to try?

I came across Flotr2, Rickshaw, jqChart, HighCharts, I am wondering if people can share first hand experience for such use case.

In case this is not a realistic goal, what would the closest performance be with today's technology?

Comment: I think a dashboard type of page should be a summary of each chart, meaning maybe the last 10 or 20 points. If they want to see data in the realms of 5000 points, they should dig into a different page that is specific to that chart.

Answer (score 4):

I think [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/Default.aspx) can meet your requirements:

> jqChart takes advantages of HTML5 Canvas to deliver *high performance client-side charts* and graphs across browsers ..

The render speed of the Line Chart is optimized for handling a large set of data. This [line chart example](http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/chart/ChartPerformance/LineChart) shows 2 series at 60,000 points each.

*Disclaimer: I am CTO of jqChart.*